# Keeping duplicate tuple values if they are present inside separate tuples but only keeping unique tuple values if they are in the same tuple

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, tuples

I have a list of tuples:

What I want to do is to keep only the `entities` which have unique numbers inside each tuple.

```
dataset = [('made of iron oxide', {'entities': [(12, 16, 'PRODUCT'), (17, 20, 'PRODUCT'), (15, 24, 'PRODUCT'), (12, 19, 'PRODUCT')]}),('made of ferric oxide', {'entities': [(10, 15, 'PRODUCT'), (17, 20, 'PRODUCT'), (624, 651, 'PRODUCT'), (30, 15, 'PRODUCT'), (1937, 1956, 'PRODUCT')]})]
```

From here, expected output is:

```
[('made of iron oxide', {'entities': [(12, 16, 'PRODUCT'), (17, 20, 'PRODUCT'), (15, 24, 'PRODUCT')]}), ('made of ferric oxide', {'entities': [(10, 15, 'PRODUCT'), (17, 20, 'PRODUCT'), (624, 651, 'PRODUCT'), (1937, 1956, 'PRODUCT')]})]
```

Code till now:

```
dataset = [('made of iron oxide', {'entities': [(12, 16, 'PRODUCT'), (17, 20, 'PRODUCT'), (15, 24, 'PRODUCT'), (12, 19, 'PRODUCT')]}),('made of ferric oxide', {'entities': [(10, 15, 'PRODUCT'), (17, 20, 'PRODUCT'), (624, 651, 'PRODUCT'), (30, 15, 'PRODUCT'), (1937, 1956, 'PRODUCT')]})]

seen_values = []
clean_data = []

# loop through each sentence and dict of values
for sentence, values in dataset:
    for value in values['entities']:

        if value[0] in seen_values:
            # remove if we have seen this before
            values['entities'].remove(value)
        else:
            # add to list if we have not seen this before
            seen_values.append(value[0])
    clean_data.append((sentence, values))

print(clean_data)
```

which gives `[('made of iron oxide', {'entities': [(12, 16, 'PRODUCT'), (17, 20, 'PRODUCT'), (15, 24, 'PRODUCT')]}), ('made of ferric oxide', {'entities': [(10, 15, 'PRODUCT'), (624, 651, 'PRODUCT'), (30, 15, 'PRODUCT'), (1937, 1956, 'PRODUCT')]})]`

Can someone help me with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
data = dataset = [('made of iron oxide', {'entities': [(12, 16, 'PRODUCT'), (17, 20, 'PRODUCT'), (15, 24, 'PRODUCT'), (12, 19, 'PRODUCT')]}),('made of ferric oxide', {'entities': [(10, 15, 'PRODUCT'), (17, 20, 'PRODUCT'), (624, 651, 'PRODUCT'), (30, 15, 'PRODUCT'), (1937, 1956, 'PRODUCT')]})]
res = []
for x in data:
    t, flag = [], set()
    for d in x[1]['entities']:
        if d[0] not in flag and d[1] not in flag:
                t.append(d)
        flag.update(d[:2])
    res.append((x[0], {'entities': t}))

print(res)
```

**Output:**

```
[('made of iron oxide', {'entities': [(12, 16, 'PRODUCT'), (17, 20, 'PRODUCT'), (15, 24, 'PRODUCT')]}), ('made of ferric oxide', {'entities': [(10, 15, 'PRODUCT'), (17, 20, 'PRODUCT'), (624, 651, 'PRODUCT'), (1937, 1956, 'PRODUCT')]})]
```